# How to expand coc.nvim incoming calls

Tags: coc.nvim

In `Coc.nvim`, when I request `document.showIncomingCalls`, I get the tree with only one successor showing up with a `+` sign in its left like the following:

```
- f1
  + f2
```

How do I expand the `+` beside `f2` to show the caller of `f2` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `<tab>` on `f2` will open actions menu. You can change it with `:h coc-config-tree-key-actions`.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I was hoping there is a way to just expand it like a tree, but apparently there is none. But at least now I can navigate it.